# in R how to escape single ' in variable which is then sent to sqlQuery

Tags: r, escaping

In R, I want to send a variable which contains single quote ' to sqlQuery, like below:

```
CASE_NO <- ('001','002')
sqlQuery(db, paste('select * from table A where col_1 in CASE_NO'))
```

Can not run directly as above as i need to escape the ' in CASE_NO variable. Try to subsititue ' with \' like below:

```
CASE_NO <- gsub(" ' "," \' ",CASE_NO)
```

but not work. Anybody know how?

Comment: I'm not sure, because the syntax you have here doesn't entirely make sense. `CASE_NO <- c("'001'","'002'")` or `CASE_NO <- c('\'001\'','\'002\'')` should work, but your second line won't do the substitution you want